# Converting Caffe MemNet model to coreML

Tags: objective-c, machine-learning, caffe, coreml, coremltools

I've converted this [Caffee](http://memorability.csail.mit.edu/memnet.tar.gz) model to coreML model with coremltools. This model predicts the visual memorability of an image.

The conversion command I used is:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('memnet.caffemodel', 'deploy.prototxt', 'mean.binaryproto'), image_input_names='data')
coreml_model.save('MemNet.mlmodel')
```

In my Objective-C project I used this code:

```
 MemNet* memnet = [[MemNet alloc] init];
  
 VNCoreMLModel* memnetModel = [VNCoreMLModel modelForMLModel: memnet.model error:nil];
  
 VNCoreMLRequest* memnetRq = [[VNCoreMLRequest alloc] initWithModel: memnetModel completionHandler: (VNRequestCompletionHandler) ^(VNRequest *request, NSError *error){
    VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation *result = ((VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation *)request.results.firstObject);
    double prediction = result.featureValue.doubleValue;
  }];
  
  NSArray *a = @[memnetRq];
  NSDictionary *d = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
  VNImageRequestHandler *handler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCIImage:image options:d];
  NSError* error;
  [handler performRequests:a error:&error];
```

The problem is that in the completion handler, when I'm getting the request result, the type of the `featureValue` is `MLFeatureTypeMultiArray`

> Double 1 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1 array

and not `MLFeatureTypeDouble` as expected.

What should I fix to get the feature value in doubles as expected?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?